# iOS registerForRemoteNotifications does not generate an error but does not fire delegate that gives device token

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

All are working fine upto today morning, I need device token to move forward
When I debug on the iOS device niether **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** nor **didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError** method is never fired off. I will really appreciate some help. My code follows.

```
        - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0){

        UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
        UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

        UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
        //[application registerForRemoteNotifications];


    }else{
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
    return YES;
    }

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: %@", deviceToken);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    NSString *deviceID = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    deviceID = [deviceID stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"Device_Token     -----> %@\n",deviceID);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceID forKey:@"KiviDeviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);

    if (error.code == 3010) {
        NSLog(@"Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error);
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    NSLog(@"NotificationSettings: %@", notificationSettings);
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

I have checked 
*iOS settings app notifications are enabled, that method will not get called*

I need some help for  "Troubleshooting Push Notifications" "If neither delegate callback application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: nor application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: is called, 
*NotificationSettings are getting*
I think call back is not calling because connection is not yet been establihed."

Comment: read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453587/apns-bug-since-today-didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-not-gett

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information :)

Answer (score 0):

There has been issues on Apples end with APNS. For some reason apps in production work fine, but apps which people are developing won't push any notifications whatsoever.

[Click here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453587/apns-bug-since-today-didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-not-gett)